# Data annotation library containing greater then etc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, data-annotations

Is there a data annotation library I can use, which contains checks between different fields, for example:

```
public Nullable<int> EstimateLow { get; set; }

[GreaterThenCheck("EstimateLow", "The high estimate must be greater then the low estimate.")]
public Nullable<int> EstimateHigh { get; set; }
```

I'd prefer not to write my own set of validators for all cases like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is such library for validating ASP.NET MVC models: http://foolproof.codeplex.com/ .
**But** it looks like early beta.